# How i can refresh bootstrap navbar?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When i add dynamically a element to navbar this lose the css format.
I trying using .navbar but not works, please help me, see the jsfiddle.

```
$('#navBar1').navbar();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BernardoBJ/y14ss9s6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

You're appending each part separately, rather than you should append them *once*:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#MainMenu').append('<li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reports</a></li>');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navBar1">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="MainMenu">
          <li>  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            APPLICATIONS <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown">Submenu</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are appending all of the code to the #navBar1 including the anchor. The anchor should actually be appended to the li.

If you append everything as one string it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#MainMenu').append('<li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reports</a></li>');
});
```

If you need to do it step by step like you are currently doing. Try something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/y14ss9s6/1/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $li = $('<li />');
    var $a = $('<a />', {
        href: "#",
        class: "dropdown-toggle",
        html: 'Reports'
    });
    $li.append($a);
    $('#MainMenu').append($li);
});
```